# Create multi-term in new frame

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to create a multi-term in a new frame using a shortcut. I tried this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (make-frame) (multi-term)))
```

This creates a new frame but creates the multi-term in the old frame. Any suggestions?

(It would also be nice to know *why* this does not work. If I do this by hand, it works. Is `make-frame` asynchronous?) (Edit: Ok, I guess it works because my window manager switches to the newly created frame, so maybe I'll have to switch frames first?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `select-frame` to select the newly created frame, the subsequent commands will then be executed in the newly created frame.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () 
                               (interactive) 
                               (select-frame (make-frame))
                               (multi-term)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (make-frame) (other-frame 0) (multi-term)))
```